# Create Prometheus Pod with persistent volume on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

Hey everyone Maybe you can help me :)
I created a Kubernetes test environment on GKE and try to deploy a monitoring solution on Prometheus platform.
I created the a StorageClass:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: gce-pd-retained
reclaimPolicy: Retain
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  replication-type: none
```

Then, created the PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-demo-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: gce-pd-retained
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

I saw that the disk is created on the UI
Then I created the Pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: promepod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: prome
    image: prom/prometheus
    args:
      - "--storage.tsdb.retention.time=12h"
      - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
      - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/"
    volumeMounts:
    - name: testvlm
      mountPath: /etc/prometheus/
    - name: testvlm
      mountPath: /prometheus/
  volumes:
    - name: testvlm
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc-demo-disk
```

**But it keep failing with this error:**
ts=2022-11-05T11:58:00.825Z caller=main.go:455 level=error msg="Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml)" file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml err="open /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: no such file or directory"

anyone can guide me what am I doing wrong?
This is from the describe:

```
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      --storage.tsdb.retention.time=12h
      --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Sat, 05 Nov 2022 13:58:00 +0200
      Finished:     Sat, 05 Nov 2022 13:58:00 +0200
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  11
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/prometheus/ from testvlm (rw)
      /prometheus/ from testvlm (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-qtbwh (ro)
```

I will appreciate any help!
Thanks!

I writing the whole details above

Comment: You created an empty volume and mounted it in `/etc/prometheus/`. Therefore, the required file `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` does not exist

Comment: Thanks Yarden! But how I can create the necessary files inside the volume?
Mount the disk on some available VM and manually create them?

Comment: As a first step, remove the volumeMount to `/etc/prometheus`. That should let the pod spin up. Afterwards, you could mount a `ConfigMap` to configure `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`

Comment: I created a configmap and then update the POD yaml.
Now, I getting those errors:
ts=2022-11-05T13:02:16.066Z caller=query_logger.go:91 level=error component=activeQueryTracker msg="Error opening query log file" file=/prometheus/queries.active err="open /prometheus/queries.active: permission denied"
panic: Unable to create mmap-ed active query log

Comment: Have a look at this [guide](https://devopscube.com/setup-prometheus-monitoring-on-kubernetes/)

Comment: Thanks I manage to get this work
I create a security context for the pod with the following configuration:
    runAsUser: 0
    runAsNonRoot: false
    runAsGroup: 0
    fsGroup: 0
Now the pod is running  so thanks for the help!!